# converting char* to array of uint8_t (c)

Tags: c, char, ipv6, uint8t

I can make function calls and receive an array of strings that represents ipv6 adress. it looks something like this

```
char* buffer=resolver_getstring(config, INI_BOOT_MESHINTFIPADDRESS);
```

if i printed buffer i will gate the ipv6 adress in string form:

```
dddd:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:cccc
```

however, the way how ipv6 address is represented in my project is with 16 hexadecimal number by using uint8_t datatype as follows

```
uint8_t ipadress[16]
```

now my problem is how can i cast (or copy the memory of buffer) to uint8_t[16]

what i would like to get is

```
    ipadress[0]=dd // hexadecimal number
    ipaddress[1]=dd
    ....
    ipaddress[15]=cc
```

is there anyway i could do ?
Regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
...
char *buffer="dddd:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:cccc";
uint8_t ipadress[16];
sscanf(buffer,
    "%2" SCNx8 "%2" SCNx8 ":"
    "%2" SCNx8 "%2" SCNx8 ":"
    "%2" SCNx8 "%2" SCNx8 ":"
    "%2" SCNx8 "%2" SCNx8 ":"
    "%2" SCNx8 "%2" SCNx8 ":"
    "%2" SCNx8 "%2" SCNx8 ":"
    "%2" SCNx8 "%2" SCNx8 ":"
    "%2" SCNx8 "%2" SCNx8 ,
    &ipadress[0],&ipadress[1],
    &ipadress[2],&ipadress[3],
    &ipadress[4],&ipadress[5],
    &ipadress[6],&ipadress[7],
    &ipadress[8],&ipadress[9],
    &ipadress[10],&ipadress[11],
    &ipadress[12],&ipadress[13],
    &ipadress[14],&ipadress[15]);
```

Comment: However, this methods generates error " expected ')' before 'SCNx8' in gcc compiler. it compiles and runs with out a problem in g++
any idea why and how it can be compiled with gcc?

Comment: @lferasu `#include <inttypes.h>` and add `-std=c99` option or `"%2" SCNx8 "%2" SCNx8 ":"` replace to `"%2hhx%2hhx:"`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look into `strtok()` (to break the string into pieces at the colon char), `strtol()` (to convert the pieces from hexadecimal form into binary) and some bit shifting and shuffling (to break the resulting 16 bit numbers into two separate bytes).

Comment: thats right i did split the string, i now have array of 16 strings, something like this
char** tokens;
*(tokens+0) ="dd"
*(tokens+1)="dd"
what is left is now to copy this elements of tokens to my ipadress
any info about the bit shifting and shuffling would be appriciated

Comment: did you look up strol() as suggested above?